# Запрос к БД Access на C#

Tags: c#, framework, visual-studio-2013, ms-access, mdb

Имеется база типа MS Access (mdb), состоящая из нескольких таблиц. На framework 4.5 всё работает, когда перевожу на 4.0 то перестаёт создаваться подключение(срабатывает исключение именно на строке connection.Open(); ).

[image: часть кода]

[image: часть кода]

Может кто знаешь, в чём может быть проблема. Нужно, чтобы всё работало именно на framework 4.0

Вот что показывает исключение (ошибка).

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Что за ошибка? Текст ошибки покажите.

Comment: добавил скрин исключения

Comment: Посмотрите тут множество вариантов решения: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine, http://www.sql.ru/forum/984579/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-ne-zaregistrirovan, http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/464072/The-Microsoft-Jet-OLEDB-provider-is-not-regist, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289764/does-net-4-0-come-with-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0

Comment: огромное спасибо, вся соль была в битности приложения..

Comment: Хорошо, оформлю как ответ. Пометьте его, пожалуйста, как верный, чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа.

Comment: дело в том, что именно на 64 не работает, я 86 поставил и всё заработалоо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте битность приложения: x86, x64.

Если x86, то измените на X64 (либо наоборот):

Project ---> Properties ---> Build --->Target Framework ---> X64

Также см. дополнительно здесь:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

http://www.sql.ru/forum/984579/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-ne-zaregistrirovan

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/464072/The-Microsoft-Jet-OLEDB-provider-is-not-regist

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289764/does-net-4-0-come-with-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0